# How to determine if apps from market are obfuscated?

Tags: android

I'm doing a project for school where I need analyze some Android apps from the Google Play Store. It's 10 apps. Is that any way to know if code is obfuscated?

I've used dax2jar for decompiling and jd-gui to open jar files, and now I can see Java code, but I'm not so good at this type of thing, and I can't determine if code is obfuscated or not.

Is the code obfuscated only when there are a lot of classes, called things like `a , b , b , c , d , e` ?

Comment: Where the variable, class etc names are meaningless (e.g. a, b, c) then almost certainly yes, most likely with ProGuard. Put simply, decide if any sane developer would have written the code as you see it - if not then consider it obfuscated. However there is no way to be 100% certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obfuscation is the hiding of intended meaning, therefore in my opinion any part of the code (class, method or variable) which purpose can't be determined by it's name can be considered as obfuscated.

Basically, yes, there would be classes and methods with weird names, like a, b, c, d... but some parts of the application could still remain not obfuscated for some reasons. It's possible to exclude classes or methods from obfuscation.